# Help identify a water level sensor in humidifier

Tags: transducer, piezoelectricity

I have this ultrasonic humidifier that looks like this:
[image]

It has a piezoelectric transducer that produces the vapor. It also has a sensor that turns it off when the water runs out. The unit now just switches off once I turn it on and I think its the low water sensor that is giving false readings. Only thing is, I'm not sure how this low water sensor reader works.

It looks like it has some little metal plate suspended on a spring that goes next to the transducer. Can anyone help identify how this is sensing the water level, and potentially how I can 'hack' it to alter the reading.

[image]
[image]
The chip on the board has no markings on it...
[image]

Comment: Water's conductive, so perhaps it's just sensing when some circuit gets broken by the water level being too low?

Comment: Looks like it might just be a capacitive sensor.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany I second capacitive sensor.

Comment: Is there a contact inside the spring on the PCB? Can't tell from the photo.

Comment: What's going on with the 4 tracks attached to the tab of Q2 and the solder blob near the _L_ in LED8? Some sort of tuning stub?

Comment: @sstobbe yes the sprint connects to P1 on the board. The spring has only 1 connector though.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany can it be a capacitive sensor if it doesn't touch the water? The only thing that gets in contact with the water is the piezo, and the spring has only 1 connector

Comment: @AlexS  Indeed it can be. If the piezo is grounded, that's the other side, or even if it isn't the water will have a lot of capacitance with respect to ground (similar to how capacitive keypads work on mobile phones).

Comment: @AlexS I wasn't sure if  the spring was used a basic float switch, pushing the entire plastic assembly up when the water is gone (less weight) and thus breaking contact with a small leaf spring internal to the coiled spring.

Comment: @AlexS Any luck in finding out how that water sensing thing works? Mine is exactly the same as your humidifier and giving same issue. I also guessed the sensor was giving false info then cut the circuitry